# Como retornar todos os grupos que participo do facebook em rss, json, php

Tags: json, facebook, rss

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida já pesquisei em todos lugares mas o facebook mudou api, e não esta retonando os grupos, gostaria de saber se tem como retornar em algum formato todos os links dos meus grupos ou alguma forma de tratar essa pagina https://www.facebook.com/groups/?category=membership retornando apenas os links

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o SDK para mostrar todos os grupos que um membro:

[`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/)

Precisarás da permisão `user_groups` e/ou `user_managed_groups` para listar os grupos que o membro gere.

o Endpoint é `"/{user-id}/groups"` ou `"/me/groups"` se for para mostrar os grupos do membro que está autenticado.

---

como exemplo, copia o códio abaixo e coloca na [página de testes do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/), clica em "Run code" (botão azul) e depois clica no link que vao mostrar abaixo da caixa onde metes o código que dirá "Mostra os meus grupos"

```
<a href="#" id="run-btn">Mostra os meus grupos</a>
<ul id="groups"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('run-btn').onclick = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {

console.log("Login ------------------------------");
console.log(response);

        getAllGroups(response.authResponse.userID);
      } else {
        // o utilizador nao deu permissoes...
      }
  }, {scope: 'user_groups'});
  return false;
}

function getAllGroups() {
  FB.api("/me/groups", function (response) {

console.log("Groups ------------------------------");
console.log(response);

      if (response && !response.error) {
         for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
            var group = response.data[i];
            document.getElementById("groups").innerHTML += 
                 "<li><a href='https://www.facebook.com/groups/" + group.id + "'>" + group.name + "</a> (" + group.id + ")</li>";
         }
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

retorno do código acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: balexandre no consele funciona perfeitamente pas usando minha appid só mostra o grupo que gerencio vc sabe pq?

Comment: precisa do `scope: user_groups` ao fazer a autenticacao...

Comment: mesmo com a permissão só mostra o que gerencio :/ mas só de listar pelo console já me ajudou muito valeu

Comment: @user2677216 se consegues ver os que és admin, é porque estás a usar `user_managed_groups`, mas precisas tambem de usar, como disse antes e na resposta o `user_groups`... tens de voltar a autenticar com a nova permissão para retornar elementos... não sabendo como te estás a autenticar, não posso ajudar muito mais... Já agora, se te ajudou, marca como resposta certa para que outros com a mesma perguntam vejam o que precisam de fazer. :)